# Does a rotating rigid ring (or other rotating rigid body) in space generate heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, angular-momentum, momentum, rigid-body-dynamics, centrifugal-force

I don't have training in physics (so forgive me if I use the wrong terms or mix up concepts), but I was thinking about “artificial gravity” in space. If a spaceship were being propelled by some force, a passenger would experience an acceleration. So ok, I’m pretty much ok with that situation. In a sci-fi rotating ring spaceship, however, a passenger would also experience an "artificial gravity" acceleration on the inside of the ring. Presumably once the ring is pushed to spin by an initial force, it will continue to spin at a constant speed without further pushing. It’s not clear to me clear what force is producing the acceleration a passenger on the ring experiences (after the ring is freely spinning). My guess is that stress in the rigid structure of the ring itself is the source of force in this scenario. But if that’s true, wouldn’t the ring be generating heat due to that stress? And if the ring is generating heat without needing to be pushed, that seems like a violation of thermodynamics—one could imagine harvesting that heat to do work. Does this mean that the rotating ring would eventually stop rotating (due to some loss of momentum into the microstructure of the ring, perhaps)? Or perhaps once the ring is freely rotating at a constant speed, there would be no stress on the structure? If that’s so, why DOESN'T the ring experience stress once it’s rotating at a constant speed? Where have I gone wrong in my reasoning?

This is my first post here. Thanks in advance, everyone!

Comment: A piece of advice. Avoid asking multiple questions. Focus on one or two. Otherwise you post is likely to be closed.

Comment: Understood! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

> Presumably once the ring is pushed to spin by an initial force, it
> will continue to spin at a constant speed without further pushing.

The ring is made to spin by the action of a net torque on it. Net torque causes *angular acceleration*: the ring starts spinning at increasing *angular velocity* ("$\text{RPM}$", if you like). This angular velocity continues to increase, until the net torque is removed altogether. Once there is no more net torque acting on the ring, it continues spinning at constant angular velocity.

> It’s not clear to me clear what force is producing the acceleration a
> passenger on the ring experiences (after the ring is freely spinning).

A person sitting on the ring experiences something called *centripetal acceleration* ($a_c$), which is caused by the constantly changing direction of the person's velocity vector $\vec{v}$. And where there's acceleration, there's force (as per $\text{N2L}$). This force, known as the *centripetal force*, is what the person experiences as 'artificial gravity'.

> My guess is that stress in the rigid structure of the ring itself is
> the source of force in this scenario. But if that’s true, wouldn’t the
> ring be generating heat due to that stress?

There is stress in the ring but it's not the kind that can cause internal heating: the stress is *static*. Only *dynamic stress*, e.g. constant flexing and relaxing at a certain frequency, can cause heating (by [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#:%7E:text=Hysteresis%20is%20the%20dependence%20of,field%20changed%20in%20the%20past.)).

Comment: Thanks for the clear responses!

Comment: Fun fact:  Dynamic stress has in fact been known to cause a satellite’s rotation to change.  See [Explorer 1.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorer_1)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert hmmm... interesting!